# How to use saved Keras Model for sentiment classification?

Tags: keras, word2vec

I trained my model and got the accuracy of 79% for sentiment classification. For embedding layer, I used word2vec. 
Now that I have my model trained and saved, how do I use it in such a way that I can put some input as a sentence and it shows me how much positive/negative by probability the sentence is?

Given below is some relevant code.

```
word_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(train_x+test_x, size=100, min_count=1, window=5, iter=100)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=emdedding_size, 
                weights=[pretrained_weights]))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters,
             kernel_size,
             padding='valid',
             activation='relu',
             strides=1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(train_x, train_y,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

Comment: I have the impression that the format of `keras.layers.Embedding` with `weights` is deprecated if you check this (https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) and this (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass strings (or 'sentences' in this case) directly to predict. [`Predict`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) accepts the input data as the numpy arrays.
So, you need to process your new input sentence the same way you processed your train data.

I can't see what you did with your train data but the process is usually the same :

- Clean
- Tokenize
- Vectorize
- Match the word index
- Pad
- Flatten

Then you can pass the resulting numpy array to predict to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you only compile the model, you have not trained anything at this point. After training it using `fit`, you can call `predict` on the trained model to feed new, unseen input. Here is an [overview](https://keras.io/models/model/) over all basic functions.

Comment: I forgot to write the 'fit' in the question. I have edited the question now.

Comment: @NicoSid, if my answer, i.e. call predict on model, solves your problem (it should), please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: I know that I have to use the predict. The question is how do I pass the damn sentence?

Comment: format your new sentence (or sentences) in the same way you formatted you training data (train_x) and feed it into the predict method, which is parameter x in the documentation.